# Изменение позиции элемента при каждом нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

В форме имеется Grid (который выходит за рамки формы) и кнопка.

**Вопрос:** каким образом я могу сдвинуть Grid в нужном мне направлении (Например влево) на определенное число в Margin при каждом нажатии кнопки?

Т.е кнопку нажал, к Grid прибавилось значение, например 50 к margin left, езе раз нажал, еще столько же прибавилось

Comment: создать свойство `marginLeft` во `VM`, привязать `Margin` к этому свойству.  создать команду которая будет увеличивать это свойство.

Comment: я не понимаю каким образом это сделать..Перепробовала многое, вот код кнопки  `private void right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thickness margin = Block_1.Margin;
            this.Block_1.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(margin.Left = 50), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.10)));
        }`  но она не корректно работает и не прибавляет margin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Thickness margin = Block_1.Margin; 
    margin.Left += 50;
    this.Block_1.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.10)));
}
```

Comment: Код подходит, но перемещение какое то странное, вместо конкретной позиции влево элемент сдвигается вправо вниз (

Comment: @Елизавета, обновил.

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!

Comment: @Елизавета, Пожалуйста!