# Ограничить перемещение Grid по Margin

Tags: c#, wpf

При нажатии на кнопку у меня сдвигается Grid с элементами, но если много раз нажимать - Grid уезжает очень далеко, как я могу ограничить его передвижение?

Ширина Grid 1700 и на половину уходит за рамки формы, 
его margin -

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,-722,0">
```

Ограничить нужно до

```
<Grid Margin="-722,0,0,0">
```

Подскажите, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему предыдущему [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574752/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8) в обработчике события нужно делать проверку на отступ.

```
private void right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Thickness margin = Block_1.Margin; 
    if (margin.Left <= -722)
    {
        margin.Left += 50;
        this.Block_1.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.10)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, единственная проблема в том, что если я буду нажимать на кнопку, пока не настанет предел и потом нажму на левую кнопку то Grid не сдвигается, а остается на половину торчать слева...   Имею ввиду - как мне сделать метод на противоположную кнопку?

Comment: @Елизавета, сделайте метод для другой кнопки, только там уже уменьшайте `margin.Left`

Comment: `Thickness margin = getBlockName.Margin;

                if (margin.Left <= -722)
                {
                    margin.Left -= 250;
                    getBlockName.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)));
                }`    Вы имеете ввиду так? в данном случае у меня вообще ничего не происходит, при нажатии на кнопки

Comment: @Елизавета, условие то нужно поменять на `>=`. У вас не заходит в блок кода так как уже вы перешли границу

Comment: Проблема только с левой, правую починила... Левая кнопка возвращает не полностью  Grid..  ` if (margin.Left <= -722)
                {
                    margin.Left += 200;
                    getBlockName.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)));
                }`

Comment: @Елизавета, приведите код обеих кнопок и скриншоты что конкретно не получается

Comment: Все работает, я подогнала нужные мне параметры, спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Скажите, а я могу прикрутить к этим методам (влево вправо) еще и колесо мышки?

Comment: @Елизавета, можно подписаться на событие `MouseWheel` в главном окне `Window`. В обработчике по свойству `Delta`, в зависимости от того отрицательное или положительное оно, можно узнать в какую сторону было вращение колесика

Comment: А могу ли я прикрутить MouseWheel к TabControl  по событию PreviewMouseWheel ?

Comment: @Елизавета, просто подпишитесь на `PreviewMouseWheel ` в `TabControl`. MouseWheel срабатывает где бы ни находился курсор, а PreviewMouseWheel если вращение было над подписавшимся элементом

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Елизавета, пожалуйста!